# Integrate Android Studio's "Inspect Code" into CI?

Tags: android, android-studio, continuous-integration, android-lint

I understand that lint is one of approaches of Android Studio's [Inspect Code](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections) and executable by gradle task, so I could integrate it into CI effortlessly.

Although Inspect Code could be triggered through terminal according to the [IntelliJ doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html)
, the script has dependency on Android Studio(IntelliJ) IDE itself which doesn't exist in my CI environment.

Inspect code's several approaches are really helpful, but I'd like to know is it possible to integrate them all into CI process?